# CentOS kernel compilation errors

Tags: linux-kernel, centos, kernel, centos6

This is my first time doing this. I need to recompile the kernel to change some settings to get a better performance out of a specific application I will run on this machine.

I followed [this](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Custom_Kernel) tutorial step by step and changed my settings in `make menucofig`.

After trying to build the rpm, I get the following error log: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/N89hSuNz)

This is really confusing as I haven't made any major changes to the config, which makes me thing there's something wrong with the tutorial. Will post all changes in menuconfig if requested.

Comment: What is content of your patch file (`linux-kernel-test.patch`)? Did you try to build kernel without patch? (It would take some time, but such way you will be sure that unmodified sources are OK, and problem is only within you patch).

Comment: @Tsyvarev I use no patch. It's the original source from http://vault.centos.org/6.7/os/Source/SPackages/ with no patches applied. Also might I add that it's the same exact kernel version I have installed.